# Select data from multiple databases into a table variable

Tags: sql-server

[Using SQL-Server] I have a situation where I need to select data from multiple databases into a table variable for later processing. It looks a little like this:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(idx INT IDENTITY(1,1), dbname VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @ids VALUES ('db1'), ('db2'), ('db3'), ..., ('dbn')

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    dbname      VARCHAR(100),
    column1     VARCHAR(100),
    column2     VARCHAR(100),
    ...
    columnn     VARCHAR(100)
)

SELECT @i = MIN(idx) - 1, @cnt = MAX(idx) FROM @ids

WHILE @i < @cnt
BEGIN
    SELECT @i = @i + 1
    SELECT @dbname=dbname FROM @ids WHERE idx = @i

    --here my trouble starts
    INSERT INTO @MyTable
    SELECT @dbname, column1, column2, ..., columnn
    FROM [@MyDB].[dbo].[SomeTable]

    ...

END
```

The final select statement should insert data (including the database name in @dbname) from the database in @MyDB into the table held in @MyTable. The above doesn't work, I have also tried:

```
SET MyQuery = 'INSERT INTO @MyTable
                SELECT ''' + @dbname + ''', column1, column2, ..., columnn
                FROM [' + @MyDB + '].[dbo].[SomeTable]'
EXEC  sp_executesql @MyQuery
```

but that fails too (it does not like the @MyTable there, not if I put that in quotes either).

How do I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: a table variable becomes out of scope when used with dynamic sql. If you change your @table variable to a #temp table, then you will be able to insert into it.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm talking about using the temp table with the dynamic SQL approach. Also read [this article on dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Use a temporary table like @Jeremy sais. Also it's a bad habit to not have your column names in your insert statement. You should write `INSERT INTO #MyTable(dbname,column1,...,columnN) SELECT ...`.